# Get first two character of first name AND first character of last name in Python using Indexing and Splice():

Tags: python, indexing, splice

I Would like to store in a variable the first 2 chars of a first name and then the first char of a last name in Python. **I have to use the Splice() along with the indexing**.

For example: John Doe --> JoD

I am pretty new to Python, and this is what I have come up to so far.

```
def getCharsOfName(name):
  initials= ""
  for c in name:
    initials += c[0]
  print(initials)

  
name = input("Enter your name (in two words)")
name = name.split(' ')
getCharsOfName(name)
```

Output --> JD (should be JoD)

I defined a function for this operation.

I can only manage to print the initials right now, I thought to include a condition on the second pass of the for loop but I could not find a proper solution.

Has anybody an idea on how I could make this work ?

Thank you,

Comment: You could do something like `a, b = name.split(" ")` and then `print(a[:2] + b[0])`.

Comment: Amazing solution. I would have never thought that in Python we can store values to variables in the same time just like that. So is that 'a' stores name[0] and 'b' stores name[1] of the list. is that right?

Comment: @MarcoStevanella Yes. That's called "unpacking". Of course this will fail if you don't have the correct number of items. So `x, y = 'Donald Duck'.split()` will work while `x, y = 'John F. Kennedy'.split()` will give you the error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

Comment: Oh thank you for the clarification, but in this very case it fits the scope. The problem feature assumes it is first name and last name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use split along the space. Then use list_after_split[0][0:2] for the firstname, and list_after_split[1][0:1] for the lastname. Then just join (add) the two strings together.

Comment: Another concept I was missing I guess. name =["Jhon","Doe"].  name[0][0:2] --> name["John"]["Jo"] where ["Jo"] is a substring right? same concept for Doe. Thank you